# How can I reduce temperature of a hot water tap without adjusting the boiler?

Tags: plumbing, uk

I'm probably asking for trouble with this question, but here goes....

I had tenants complaining of a luke warm shower and discovered that their boiler hot water temperature was set to about 50º.

The shower has a thermostatic valve and has no separate power control. As expected the mix was coming out about 38º. The manual says that at least +10º is required in the hot supply and that they recommend 60º. (Meaning that for a 43º shower they'll need at *least* 53º at the boiler, but higher in reality to get some power).

However, the bathroom sink has separate cold and hot taps (no mixer) which means they are at risk of scalding themselves. This is why they turned the boiler down.

**Is there a way - without fitting an electric shower and without replacing the bathroom taps - to have the shower temperature up as required, but keep the wash basin safe?**

Aside: Previously I had a thermostatic valve with a power handle, but tenants turned it up full blast and then complained it was cold. I figured prioritising the temperature was a better route as long as the power was acceptable.

Comment: To anyone asking why I don't just fit an electric shower, or install a mixer tap at the sink: It's a period property with traditional fittings and I want to keep it that way. I've also just spent about 400 quid getting the new shower installed.

Comment: Is an "electric shower" one that has an electric, on-demand heater to provide some additional heat as needed? Otherwise, I'm thinking "electric" and "shower" don't belong in the same sentence...

Comment: Yes. I mean boiler stays at 50 or whatever and electric shower heats water. I thought this was a common term. Googling it, it seems it is.

Comment: You can (or have a plumber) add a mixing valve directly at the hot water output from your boiler, that would limit the hot water temperature to the entire house.

Comment: It may be common, but not in the US... (or, at least not to me)

Comment: @freeman Fair enough. I always forget on here to mention UK. Models with pump for extra pressure also known as power showers over here.

Comment: Only fair, Tim - many forget that the "rest of the world" (i.e. _not_ the US) looks at this site, too. ;)

Comment: This is one of those things I find amazing how did we survive before mixing valves and drinking water out of a hose? If the water in a sink is two hot you pull your hands away. In a tub it could be different but you have a mixing valve there.

Comment: @EdBeal we *survived* with various people who were, for whatever reason, unable to pull themselves away fast enough having second degree burns, and with lots of people sick (or dying, but they didn't *survive*) from whatever was in the water they were drinking.

Comment: @ecnerwal the time to temperature at 60c / 140f it would take a full 5 seconds according to the American burn association at 65.5 /150f it would take 2 seconds and at 71.11C/170f down to 1/2 second , we’re talking about a sink the tub has a mixing valve, so someone would first have to have the water on hot and allow it to run long enough to reach full temp then hold there hands under the uncomfortably hot water for 5 seconds to get a 2nd degree burn at the 60c being discussed,  Maybe we need a little chlorine in the gene pool. Would be a more direct way of saying how did we survive?

Comment: In case I need to justify by concerns regarding danger and survival (which I don't). I have **tenants**. Tenants complain at best. Sue at worst. I'm a good landlord and their grievances seem reasonable. In my own home I constantly pull my hands away from the kitchen tap when I forget it's at 60º but I have nobody to complain to, so I say "ouch" and get on with my day.

Comment: I will also add that it's a combination boiler with a "comfort" setting, meaning virtually instantaneous heat at the desired temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a standalone tempering valve on the line to the sink, or (probably a larger one) on the line to "everything but the shower" which would protect the kitchen sink as well, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The kitchen has a mixer at least. Adding just to the basin supply should do it.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer before trying it. It's the only response so far that actually addresses the question I asked. I wasn't aware of such a gadget and now I am. Thanks